# fusermount: mount failed: Permission denied

Tags: mount, permissions, fuse

I'm trying to use [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse) to mount my Google Drive to an Ubuntu 13.04 VM I own on remote sever so I can copy some very large project-related files to my work computer. I've been searching the web, and none of the solutions given work.

id:

> uid=1387004(levicampbell) gid=1387004(levicampbell)
>   groups=1387004(levicampbell),27(sudo),33(www-data),103(fuse)

groups:

> levicampbell sudo www-data fuse

Contents of ~/.gdfuse/default/config:

> docs_file_extension=true
>   verification_code=4/ORfOV4B9R8rm1PpkvuLkD6vyj6rD.sl2aSyoBR0sbmmS0T3UFEsO-h0t3iQI
>   umask=0o022 document_format=odt debug=false presentation_format=pdf
>   new_revision=true spreadsheet_format=ods download_docs=false
>   client_id=628727098029.apps.googleusercontent.com drawing_format=png
>   conflict_resolution=server keep_duplicates=false
>   metadata_cache_time=60 client_secret=ASKUBUNTUEXAMPLE read_only=false
>   form_format=ods max_cache_size_mb=512 sqlite3_busy_timeout=500

Contents of ~/.gdfuse/default/gdfuse.log:

```
[0.000701] TID=0: Setting up default filesystem...
[0.000788] TID=0: Loading configuration from /home/levicampbell/.gdfuse/default/config...done
Saving configuration in /home/levicampbell/.gdfuse/default/config...done
[0.001475] TID=0: Loading application state from /home/levicampbell/.gdfuse/default/state...done
Current version: 0.5.2
Setting up cache db...done
Setting up CURL...done
Refresh token already present.
[0.004157] TID=0: Starting filesystem /home/levicampbell/Documents/
[0.031584] TID=0: Exiting.
CURL cleanup...done
Clearing context...done
```

lsmod output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
xt_multiport           12798  0 
xt_conntrack           12760  0 
xt_recent              18543  0 
ipt_REJECT             12576  0 
xt_LOG                 17829  0 
xt_limit               12711  0 
xt_tcpudp              12924  0 
xt_addrtype            12713  0 
xt_state               12578  0 
iptable_filter         12810  0 
nfnetlink_log          18038  0 
nfnetlink              14650  1 nfnetlink_log
veth                   13331  0 
aufs                  210216  7928 
sch_tbf                13251  1 
ebt_ip                 12538  68 
ebtable_broute         12731  0 
ebtable_nat            12807  0 
ebtable_filter         12827  1 
ebtables               31209  3 ebtable_broute,ebtable_nat,ebtable_filter
ipt_MASQUERADE         12880  1 
iptable_nat            13151  1 
nf_conntrack_ipv4      15063  1 
nf_defrag_ipv4         12758  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4            13316  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 21952  3 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_ipv4,iptable_nat
nf_conntrack           97581  7 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat,xt_state,nf_nat_ipv4,xt_conntrack,iptable_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4
ip_tables              27716  2 iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               34194  14 xt_recent,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,ipt_MASQUERADE,ebt_ip,xt_limit,xt_state,xt_conntrack,xt_LOG,xt_multiport,iptable_filter,ebtables,ipt_REJECT,xt_addrtype
bridge                116160  1 ebtable_broute
stp                    12976  1 bridge
llc                    14597  2 stp,bridge
ip_gre                 18288  0 
ip_tunnel              23842  1 ip_gre
gre                    14030  1 ip_gre
dm_crypt               23456  0 
joydev                 17575  0 
psmouse               108513  0 
serio_raw              13462  0 
i2c_piix4              22299  0 
mac_hid                13253  0 
rbd                    65178  39 
libceph               232021  1 rbd
btrfs                 867780  0 
xor                    21411  1 btrfs
raid6_pq               97812  1 btrfs
libcrc32c              12644  2 btrfs,libceph
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 53067  0 
hid                   106565  2 hid_generic,usbhid
floppy                 70207  0 
cirrus                 25286  1 
syscopyarea            12633  1 cirrus
sysfillrect            12901  1 cirrus
sysimgblt              12806  1 cirrus
ttm                    89884  1 cirrus
drm_kms_helper         53224  1 cirrus
drm                   308397  3 ttm,drm_kms_helper,cirrus
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I don't know enough about fuse to know. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: What command used to mount ? What permission on mount point ?  
 If something goes wrong, you can try clearing the cache, with this command:
$ google-drive-ocamlfuse -cc
If something still doesn't work, try starting from scratch removing everything in~/.gdfuse/default. In this case you will need to reauthorize the application.

Comment: At what point does it say permission denied?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior in 13.10?

Comment: Since it's a permission problem; maybe all you need to do is stick `sudo` before your commands. Like `sudo whatever...`

Comment: Did you wait for the app to receive the authorization tokens on installation? There's a step by step tutorial that may prove helpful [here] [1] [1]:http://mylinuxbook.com/google-drive-ocamlfuse-a-fuse-filesystem-over-google-drive-lets-you-mount-your-google-drive-under-linux/